# Macro program does not run continuously...Run only a single time

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to macro programming with excel and I want to continuously sort the column A once a data is input. But it does not work. It sort once and stops. Can you please help me on this? Thank you very much...

```
Sub Macro3(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("A2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub

Sub sort()
Dim Target As Range
Set Target = Range("Table1")
Call Macro3(Target)
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
Call sort
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you realize that by sorting the table without disabling event handling, you are running the Worksheet_Change on top of itself over and over?

Comment: I am really sorry I don't get it. Is there any way you can correct the code? So I can understand it better...Thank you

Comment: in Macro3, you did not refer to the `Target` range carrying over from Sort() but is fixed-pointing to Table1 again. Try use `Target.sort.sortfields.clear`... etc...

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable event handling before making changes to the values on the worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo out_here
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With ListObjects("Table1").Range
            .Sort key1:=.Cells(1), order1:=xlAscending, _
                  Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End If

out_here:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

That is all you need to perform the tasks you had. If you want to split the sorting code into three parts, that should be a simple matter as long as you retain the disabling of the event handling.

Comment: I don't believe sorting triggers the worksheet change event, but otherwise the simplification is good.